Refer to artifacts of PR workflow in subsequent "merged" workflow
I want to set up GitHub Actions such that creating a pull request against master will trigger a workflow that builds and unit-tests the app. Then, once accepted and merged, an other workflow should be triggered that uses the build artifacts and deploys them.
So I need a way to cross-reference from the "merged"-workflow to the previous "PR" workflow. This can be done with actions/download-artifact@v4 like so:
- name: Download artifacts
  uses: actions/download-artifact@v4
  with:
    name: my_artifact
    run-id: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.id }}
    github-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

(see this answer)
But how can I retrieve the workflow_run.id of the other workflow?
The workflow is triggered upon completion of the other workflow:
on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: ["Build and Test"]
    types:
      - completed
  workflow_dispatch:

Apparently using that it is quite easy to refer back to the previous run as documented here. However, there is the problem that I can't tag the corresponding commit properly since GitHub creates a different commit for merge request than the one that is eventually merged. So another, possibly better, trigger would be on push to master:
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

But then there doesn't seem to be a built-in way to retrieve the artifact's information.

Could you share in your question the way your are currently triggering the workflow where is located the download-artifact action?

Ok. Did you notice your can also filter this trigger by branch? You can also use ${{ github.event.workflow_run.head_branch }} (ref) in a if condition in your workflow if you need to match something more specific. Also, I don't think the github.event.workflow_run is available for workflow dispatch event (it probably won't work if the run is trigger by this event).

@GuiFalourd I saw that, but how would this help me in this regard? I would still have to retrieve the run-id if I'm correct.

Using the branch will allow you to filter the workflow run completed on the desired head branch (master). This si related to the last comment you added about pushing to the master branch. Now, regarding your issue, the github.event.workflow_run.id will only be filled in the workflow_run event trigger, not through the others event triggers. Just using on:   workflow_run:     workflows: ["Build and Test"]     types:       - completed should work.

I've got an (old) example if you want to have a look: main workflow uploading the artifact, and workflow_run workflow downloading the artifact

@GuiFalourd Thanks, it was my first intention to do it like this. However, this brings some more problems as I noticed: 1) I think github creates a seperate merge commit. The commit ref in the running action will refer to this commit ref, but the commit that is eventually merged will not be the same. This means when i assign a release tag to this commit, it will not stick on master. 2) The first issue also hinders automatic generation of release notes using the gh release cli tool afaik.
So my second take would be trigger the release& deploy stage only on push to master, not workflow_run

Understood. In that case, instead of a workflow_run trigger, an option could be using a on: release: types: [published] trigger (ref)

@GuiFalourd Yes but again, same problem: How then to get the artifacts from the previous build workflow? There's no association between the two, however it is clear that the build doesn't need to be repeated because it was already done on the pull request and nothing should have changed.

Hmmm, that's true. You want to promote your build, not building a new one in each step. You may need a customizable way to refer the workflow where the build has occurred in your workflow generating the release, or where the binary has been saved (for example using github packages or external storage tools).

@GuiFalourd It appears this problem is unsolved over all: https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact/issues/21. However, I'm wondering what does the gh download action download when I just specify the path but the artifact has been created by a different workflow?

The action will download the artifact from the previous workflow and unzip the content to the specified path location in the subsequent workflow runner instance (please, check the example I shared above using the action, it's exactly this scenario)

@GuiFalourd That would be perfect. I'm wondering if it's robust enough. Say I disable push to master and pull requests always run the build, I should never be in a situation where the build artifact is outdated?

If you manage the workflows executions correctly, yes. The build will never be outdated.
